# VTKRenderWindowInteractor in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, vtk

I am using MFC environment and VTK,
After i invoking my program ,i call the 'Start' method of VTKRenderWindowInteractor class.
The question is that , after i closed the window there is still a progress exists, i can not restart my program,because there is 
already a progress.

code:

```
extern list<vtkIdType> deleteIds;

// Define interaction style
class InteractorStyle : public vtkInteractorStyleRubberBandPick
{
public:
    static InteractorStyle* New();
    vtkTypeMacro(InteractorStyle,vtkInteractorStyleRubberBandPick);

    InteractorStyle()
    {
        this->SelectedMapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSetMapper>::New();
        this->SelectedActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
        this->SelectedActor->SetMapper(SelectedMapper);
    }

    virtual void OnLeftButtonUp()
    {
        // Forward events
        vtkInteractorStyleRubberBandPick::OnLeftButtonUp();

        vtkPlanes* frustum = static_cast<vtkAreaPicker*>(this->GetInteractor()->GetPicker())->GetFrustum();

        vtkSmartPointer<vtkExtractGeometry> extractGeometry =
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkExtractGeometry>::New();
        extractGeometry->SetImplicitFunction(frustum);
#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
        extractGeometry->SetInput(this->Points);
#else
        extractGeometry->SetInputData(this->Points);
#endif
        extractGeometry->Update();

        vtkSmartPointer<vtkVertexGlyphFilter> glyphFilter =
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkVertexGlyphFilter>::New();
        glyphFilter->SetInputConnection(extractGeometry->GetOutputPort());
        glyphFilter->Update();

        vtkPolyData* selected = glyphFilter->GetOutput();
        //std::cout << "Selected " << selected->GetNumberOfPoints() << " points." << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "Selected " << selected->GetNumberOfCells() << " cells." << std::endl;
#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
        this->SelectedMapper->SetInput(selected);
#else
        this->SelectedMapper->SetInputData(selected);
#endif
        this->SelectedMapper->ScalarVisibilityOff();

        vtkIdTypeArray* ids = vtkIdTypeArray::SafeDownCast(selected->GetPointData()->GetArray("OriginalIds"));
        if(ids)
        {
            for(vtkIdType i = 0; i < ids->GetNumberOfTuples(); i++)
            {
                deleteIds.push_back(ids->GetValue(i));
                //std::cout << "Id " << i << " : " << ids->GetValue(i) << std::endl;
            }
        }
        this->SelectedActor->GetProperty()->SetColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); //(R,G,B)
        this->SelectedActor->GetProperty()->SetPointSize(3);

        this->CurrentRenderer->AddActor(SelectedActor);
        this->GetInteractor()->GetRenderWindow()->Render();
        this->HighlightProp(NULL);
    }

    void SetPoints(vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> points) {this->Points = points;}
private:
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> Points;
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> SelectedActor;
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSetMapper> SelectedMapper;

};
vtkStandardNewMacro(InteractorStyle);

CoalStock::CoalStock(CWnd *pcWnd)
{
    this->pcWnd = pcWnd;
    this->pvtkMFCWindow     = NULL;

    // Create the the renderer, window and interactor objects.
    this->pvtkRenderer    = vtkRenderer::New();

    this->pvtkMFCWindow = new vtkMFCWindow(pcWnd);

    this->pvtkPoints = vtkPoints::New();
    this->pRemovalPoints = vtkPoints::New();
    this->polyData = vtkPolyData::New();
    this->delaunay2D = vtkDelaunay2D::New();
    this->cutEdges = vtkCutter::New();

    this->pvtkMFCWindow->GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(this->pvtkRenderer);
}
```

my class method

```
int CoalStock::PickerDeletePoint()
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkAreaPicker> areaPicker =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkAreaPicker>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    renderWindowInteractor->SetPicker(areaPicker);
    renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(this->pvtkRenderer->GetRenderWindow());

    string id = "deletePoint";
    RemoveActor();
    ShapeActorMap::iterator am_it = _actorMap.find(id);
    if (am_it != _actorMap.end ())
    {
        return -10;//if exist return -10
    }
    int ret = 1;
    if(delaunay2D->GetInput() == NULL)
    {
        ret = DelaunayPoly();
    }
    if(ret == 0) return ret;

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdFilter> idFilter =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdFilter>::New();
    idFilter->SetInput(delaunay2D->GetOutput());
    idFilter->SetIdsArrayName("OriginalIds");
    idFilter->Update();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSetSurfaceFilter> surfaceFilter =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSetSurfaceFilter>::New();
    surfaceFilter->SetInputConnection(idFilter->GetOutputPort());
    surfaceFilter->Update();

    vtkPolyData* input = surfaceFilter->GetOutput();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapPoint = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();

#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
    mapPoint->SetInputConnection(input->GetProducerPort());
#else
    mapPoint->SetInputData(input);
#endif


    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actorPoint = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    actorPoint->SetMapper(mapPoint);
    actorPoint->GetProperty()->SetColor(1, 1, 0);  //璁惧畾鏇查潰鑳岄潰棰滆壊
    mapPoint->ScalarVisibilityOff();

    actorPoint->GetProperty()->SetRepresentationToPoints();

    this->AddActorToRenderer(actorPoint);
    _actorMap[id] = actorPoint;

    vtkSmartPointer<InteractorStyle> style =
        vtkSmartPointer<InteractorStyle>::New();
    style->SetPoints(input);
    renderWindowInteractor->SetInteractorStyle( style );
    renderWindowInteractor->Initialize();
    renderWindowInteractor->Start();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

invoking

```
void CvtkDLGDlg::OnBnClickedPicker()
{
    pCoalStock->PickerDeletePoint();
}
```